# Where is it best to add a confirmation dialog popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and the latest version of `jQuery UI` and `Fluent Validation` to handle my server side validation.

I am trying to get a `jQuery dialog` to work as a confirmation popup before the form is submitted. The user should click yes to submit the form or cancel to stay on the form.

I have Googled and tried the samples given but I can't get it to work.  I have tried doing this on the button's click event, didn't work.  Now I am trying to add it to the form submit.

My HTML markup:

```
<button id="SaveButton" type="submit">Save</button>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Save Customer?">
     <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure you want to save this customer?</p>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('form').submit(function () {
          $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
          return false;
     });

     $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
               'Save': function () {
                    $('form').sumbit();
               },
               Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
               }
          }
     });
});
```

The error that I get using the method above is:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

...and it breaks on `$('form').sumbit();`

How do I get this to work properly? And where is it best to add this? On the button or when submitting the form?  Both?

**NOTE:** Answers need to be based on `jQuery` and the `jQuery dialog` control.

Comment: This is no function called `sumbit`; are you after `submit()`? It's also worth noting that jQuery UI dialogs are non-blocking...

Comment: Why not use the validation of asp.net mvc 4? you can add a partial view into your dialog and then use the mvc 4's validation form.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
$('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: [
                {
                    text : 'Save',
                    click : function () {
                        $('form').submit();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text : 'Cancel',
                    click : function () {
                         $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            ]
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: In View : @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmp", new { id = item.Id }, new { onclick = " return DeleteConfirm()" })

In script: function DeleteConfirm(){ if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete record")) return true; else return false;
}

In Controller: public ActionResult DeleteEmp(int id) { var empDelete = (from emp in dbml.M_Employees where emp.Id == id select emp).Single(); dbml.M_Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(empDelete); dbml.SubmitChanges(); return RedirectToAction("Index"); }

Comment: Answer needs to be with regards to the jQuery dialog control.